# Custom UseLayoutEffect hook firing too many times for bounding box calculation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I am working on a feature to draw a hub and spoke diagram (i.e. i have a central div with other div's around it that have svg lines connecting all the outer divs to the center). You can see a somewhat simplified, but still complete code sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-base-spoked-cards-qommx?file=/src/App.js).

To do this, I made a hook that will get the bounding box of each div using their ref. It works, but it is firing way too many times and causing a delay. espcially when it has the max number of boxes

This is the ref that gets the bounding box. **I belive this is where the issue is**:

```
import { useCallback, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";

const useBoundingBoxWithListener = (ref, childRef) => {
  const [bbox, setBbox] = useState({});

  const set = useCallback(
    () =>
      setBbox(ref && ref.current ? ref.current.getBoundingClientRect() : {}),
    [ref]
  );

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    set();
    window.addEventListener("animationend", set);
    window.addEventListener("resize", set);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("animationend", set);
      window.removeEventListener("resize", set);
    };
  }, [ref, set]);

  return { bbox, ref };
};

export { useBoundingBoxWithListener };
```

This is the component that uses the bounding box hook for each ref:

```
import React from "react";
import { locationEnum } from "./Spoke";
import { useBoundingBoxWithListener } from "./useBoundingBoxWithListener";

const useSpokes = () => {
  const middleLeftCard = React.useRef();
  const middleCard = React.useRef();
  const middleRightCard = React.useRef();
  const topLeftCard = React.useRef();
  const topMiddleCard = React.useRef();
  const topRightCard = React.useRef();
  const bottomLeftCard = React.useRef();
  const bottomMiddleCard = React.useRef();
  const bottomRightCard = React.useRef();
  const middleLeftSvgRef = React.useRef();
  const middleLeftFoRef = React.useRef();
  const middleRightSvgRef = React.useRef();
  const middleRightFoRef = React.useRef();
  const topLeftSvgRef = React.useRef();
  const topLeftFoRef = React.useRef();
  const topMiddleSvgRef = React.useRef();
  const topMiddleFoRef = React.useRef();
  const topRightSvgRef = React.useRef();
  const topRightFoRef = React.useRef();
  const bottomLeftSvgRef = React.useRef();
  const bottomLeftFoRef = React.useRef();
  const bottomMiddleSvgRef = React.useRef();
  const bottomMiddleFoRef = React.useRef();
  const bottomRightSvgRef = React.useRef();
  const bottomRightFoRef = React.useRef();

  const { bbox: middleLeftBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(middleLeftCard);
  const { bbox: middleBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(middleCard);
  const { bbox: middleRightBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(middleRightCard);
  const { bbox: topLeftBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(topLeftCard);
  const { bbox: topMiddleBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(topMiddleCard);
  const { bbox: topRightBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(topRightCard);
  const { bbox: bottomLeftBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(bottomLeftCard);
  const { bbox: bottomMiddleBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(
    bottomMiddleCard
  );
  const { bbox: bottomRightBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(bottomRightCard);

  const { bbox: middleLeftSvgBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(
    middleLeftSvgRef
  );
  const { bbox: middleRightSvgBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(
    middleRightSvgRef
  );
  const { bbox: topLeftSvgBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(topLeftSvgRef);
  const { bbox: topMiddleSvgBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(topMiddleSvgRef);
  const { bbox: topRightSvgBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(topRightSvgRef);
  const { bbox: bottomLeftSvgBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(
    bottomLeftSvgRef
  );
  const { bbox: bottomMiddleSvgBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(
    bottomMiddleSvgRef
  );
  const { bbox: bottomRightSvgBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(
    bottomRightSvgRef
  );

  const { bbox: middleLeftFoBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(middleLeftFoRef);
  const { bbox: middleRightFoBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(
    middleRightFoRef
  );
  const { bbox: topLeftFoBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(topLeftFoRef);
  const { bbox: topMiddleFoBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(topMiddleFoRef);
  const { bbox: topRightFoBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(topRightFoRef);
  const { bbox: bottomLeftFoBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(bottomLeftFoRef);
  const { bbox: bottomMiddleFoBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(
    bottomMiddleFoRef
  );
  const { bbox: bottomRightFoBox } = useBoundingBoxWithListener(
    bottomRightFoRef
  );

  const spokes = [
    {},
    {
      from: middleBox,
      to: topMiddleBox,
      fromRef: middleCard,
      toRef: topMiddleCard,
      start: locationEnum.topMiddle,
      end: locationEnum.bottomMiddle
    },
    {
      from: middleBox,
      to: bottomMiddleBox,
      fromRef: middleCard,
      toRef: bottomMiddleCard,
      start: locationEnum.bottomMiddle,
      end: locationEnum.topMiddle
    },
    {
      from: middleBox,
      to: middleLeftBox,
      fromRef: middleCard,
      toRef: middleLeftCard,
      start: locationEnum.middleLeft,
      end: locationEnum.middleRight
    },
    {
      from: middleBox,
      to: middleRightBox,
      fromRef: middleCard,
      toRef: middleRightCard,
      start: locationEnum.middleRight,
      end: locationEnum.middleLeft
    },
    {
      from: middleBox,
      to: topLeftBox,
      fromRef: middleCard,
      toRef: topLeftCard,
      start: locationEnum.topLeft,
      end: locationEnum.bottomRight
    },
    {
      from: middleBox,
      to: bottomRightBox,
      fromRef: middleCard,
      toRef: bottomRightCard,
      start: locationEnum.bottomRight,
      end: locationEnum.topLeft
    },
    {
      from: middleBox,
      to: topRightBox,
      fromRef: middleCard,
      toRef: topRightCard,
      start: locationEnum.topRight,
      end: locationEnum.bottomLeft
    },
    {
      from: middleBox,
      to: bottomLeftBox,
      fromRef: middleCard,
      toRef: bottomLeftCard,
      start: locationEnum.bottomLeft,
      end: locationEnum.topRight
    }
  ];

  const drawings = [
    {},
    {
      svgBox: topMiddleSvgBox,
      svgRef: topMiddleSvgRef,
      foreignObjectChildBox: topMiddleFoBox,
      foreignObjectChildRef: topMiddleFoRef
    },
    {
      svgBox: bottomMiddleSvgBox,
      svgRef: bottomMiddleSvgRef,
      foreignObjectChildBox: bottomMiddleFoBox,
      foreignObjectChildRef: bottomMiddleFoRef
    },
    {
      svgBox: middleLeftSvgBox,
      svgRef: middleLeftSvgRef,
      foreignObjectChildBox: middleLeftFoBox,
      foreignObjectChildRef: middleLeftFoRef
    },
    {
      svgBox: middleRightSvgBox,
      svgRef: middleRightSvgRef,
      foreignObjectChildBox: middleRightFoBox,
      foreignObjectChildRef: middleRightFoRef
    },
    {
      svgBox: topLeftSvgBox,
      svgRef: topLeftSvgRef,
      foreignObjectChildBox: topLeftFoBox,
      foreignObjectChildRef: topLeftFoRef
    },
    {
      svgBox: bottomRightSvgBox,
      svgRef: bottomRightSvgRef,
      foreignObjectChildBox: bottomRightFoBox,
      foreignObjectChildRef: bottomRightFoRef
    },
    {
      svgBox: topRightSvgBox,
      svgRef: topRightSvgRef,
      foreignObjectChildBox: topRightFoBox,
      foreignObjectChildRef: topRightFoRef
    },
    {
      svgBox: bottomLeftSvgBox,
      svgRef: bottomLeftSvgRef,
      foreignObjectChildBox: bottomLeftFoBox,
      foreignObjectChildRef: bottomLeftFoRef
    }
  ];

  return { spokes, drawings, middleCard };
};

export default useSpokes;
```

And this is the component that gets the divs ready to display.

```
const MyView = ({ children }) => {
  const layoutClasses = [
    "subject",
    "topMiddle",
    "bottomMiddle",
    "middleLeft",
    "middleRight",
    "topLeft",
    "bottomRight",
    "topRight",
    "bottomLeft"
  ];
  const { spokes, drawings, middleCard } = useSpokes();

  return (
    <div className="layout">
      {children.map((c, i) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={i}
            ref={i === 0 ? middleCard : spokes[i].toRef}
            className={`${layoutClasses[i]} timing`}
          >
            {c}
            {i > 0 ? (
              <Spoke
                text={c.props?.subjectPredicate}
                foBox={drawings[i].foreignObjectChildBox}
                foRef={drawings[i].foreignObjectChildRef}
                {...spokes[i]}
                {...drawings[i]}
              />
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And this is the component that actually displays everything:

```
    <MyView>
      <div className="card"></div>
      <div className="card" subjectPredicate={"node"}></div>
      <div className="card" subjectPredicate={"node"}></div>
      <div className="card" subjectPredicate={"node"}></div>
      <div className="card" subjectPredicate={"node"}></div>
      <div className="card" subjectPredicate={"node"}></div>
      <div className="card" subjectPredicate={"node"}></div>
      <div className="card" subjectPredicate={"node"}></div>
      <div className="card" subjectPredicate={"node"}></div>
    </MyView>
```

I've added a `console.log` in the `Spokes` components of the whole example to show how many times it's actually getting hit in the console (1000+). You can see everything working together in the code sandbox above if you'd like to fork it and try to play with it directly.

Comment: Sorry dude but I can't look at your codes! can you make it simple?

Comment: Well you add a listener on every render... You really need to make a minimal example here

Comment: tried thinking of a good way to make it minimal, but the issue is, in part, due to the complexity i think unfortunately.

Comment: @DennisVash i tried moving the listeners out to another effect that should fire less and it doesn't work. if you have any ideas to make that work properly i'm all ears! this hook seems to be the root of the problem (as far as i can tell) so maybe the rest of the complexity is better just for context

Answer (score 0):

I made a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-base-spoked-cards-forked-fxqtg?file=/src/useSpokes.js) for you to look at.

To explain though: I wrapped the `Spoke` component with `React.memo` and the re-renders for me dropped from ~2k to 272.
This didn't fix the minor delay/jump, so I removed the "timing" className you had on the parent div rendered out in the `MyView.js` component. This made the line render smoothly, but the "node" box is permanently there. Not 100% sure what the intended functionality is based on your description, just that there was an unwanted delay, but think this might be enough to put you on the right track, (it seems the functionality on your "timing" is not actually stopping the animation from running on the lines whilst your boxes move, the delay is just holding its visiblity).

Also for some reason the locationEnum was being exported from a place it was being imported, not sure if intentional?

Comment: thanks for taking a look at this. yeah, i do need to timing functionality, though maybe it will work better if I use it in with framer or something of the sort. The enum location export is a mistake. directory is different in my actual project

Answer (score 0):

Wow I figured it out! The issue was that layout effect was too early in the lifecycle! Odd because i've usually header when you're dealing with painting things on the screen it should be done with layout but i guess in this case it makes sense because you *want* them to be painted to you can get the bounding box.

Something like the below. Only issue at the moment is that it seems like there is a memory leak to plug. I'll post an update if I find it:

Edit: well, the memory leak is proving very hard to plug... might have to pass but will update if i come up with something.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useBoundingBoxWithEventListeners = (ref) => {
  const [bbox, setBbox] = useState({});

  const set = useCallback(() => 
    setBbox(ref && ref.current ? ref.current.getBoundingClientRect() : {}), [ref]);

  useEffect(() => {
    set();
    window.addEventListener('resize', set);
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', set);
    };
  }, [ref, set, bbox]);

  return {bbox, ref};
};


export { useBoundingBoxWithEventListeners };
```